# How to go about solving this question?

Tags: geometry

Problem - An open-top box is made from $14$ inch by $32$ inch piece of cardboard, as shown below. $V= L * W * H$, and the height of the box is $x$.
[image: Picture of the piece of cardboard]
I attached an image with a picture of the box. My questions are:

1. How would I begin to write and equation in factored form? I was thinking of making it:
   $(x-32)(x-32)(x-14)(x-14)$
   and factoring that. However I am not sure if that is correct. 
   The exact question was:
   "Write an equation in factored form"

2.Also, there is another question asking to:
  "Write the volume of the polynomial function in standard form"
how would I go about doing that part as well?

3.The final question on the page is:
 "Find the volume of the box if the height is $2$ inches"
However, I'm pretty sure once I understand the first $2$ parts I can just plug this in easily. This doesn't need to be explained just thought I'd add it to show you what rest was leading up to.

Thanks in advance to whoever can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $L=32-2x$, $W=14-2x$, $H=x$, so $V=(32-2x)(14-2x)x$. This is a factored form.
2. Expand the product.
3. Substitute $x=2$. The computing is easier if you use the factored form.

Comment: Thanks for help. Both answers were correct and very helpful, however this one seemed like the best.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can write $V=(32-2x)(14-2x)x$ (factored form). Then you must multiply expressions in the brackets and you will obtain polynomial form.

Comment: Classical supplementary question is: For which $x$ the volume of the box is maximal?